# Counting couples in array with loop in r

Tags: arrays, r, for-loop, if-statement, counter

I'm having some issues writing a simple for loop with conditions in r.
I've got this array:

```
Temp <- c("A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "C", "A", "B")
```

I want to count the couples in this array, by using two indexes which are incremented during the loop.It's mandatory to follow the order of the sequence.

The final result for this array should be:

```
CountAA = 1
CountAB = 2
CountAC = 1
CountBA = 1
CountBB = 0
CountBC = 0
CountCA = 1
CountCB = 0
CountCC = 1
```

I've tried with this code, but it gives me an error

```
"Error in if (Temp[i] == "A" & Temp[j] == "A") { : 
  argument is of length zero"
```

Code

```
CountAA = 0
CountAB = 0
CountAC = 0
CountBA = 0
CountBB = 0
CountBC = 0
CountCA = 0
CountCB = 0
CountCC = 0
i = 1
j = 2

for (j in 1:length(Temp)-1){
    if (Temp[i]=="A" & Temp[j]=="A"){
      CountAA = CountAA + 1
      i = i + 1
      j = j + 1
    }
    if (Temp[i]=="A" & Temp[j]=="B"){
      CountAB = CountAB + 1
      i = i + 1 
      j = j + 1
    }
    if(Temp[i]=="A" & Temp[j]=="C"){
      CountAC = CountAC + 1
      i = i + 1
      j = j + 1
    }
    if(Temp[i]=="B" & Temp[j]=="A"){
      CountBA = CountBA + 1
      i = i + 1
      j = j + 1
    }
    if(Temp[i]=="B" & Temp[j]=="B"){
      CountBB = CountBB + 1
      i = i + 1
      j = j + 1
    }
    if(Temp[i]=="B" & Temp[j]=="C"){
      CountBC = CountBC + 1
      i = i + 1
      j = j + 1
    }
    if(Temp[i]=="C" & Temp[j]=="A"){
      CountCA = CountCA + 1
      i = i + 1
      j = j + 1
    }
    if(Temp[i]=="C" & Temp[j]=="B"){
      CountCB = CountCB + 1
      i = i + 1
      j = j + 1
    }
    if(Temp[i]=="C" & Temp[j]=="C"){
      CountCC = CountCC + 1
      i = i + 1
      j = j + 1
    }
}
```

Comment: In your code you don't have to increment i and j manually - this is done with the for loop. Also `1:length(Temp)-1` isn't doing what you want it to do.

Comment: Can you make clear what format you want as an output ? it seems we're all giving you something different, but all formats are straightforward to translate to what you prefer.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper: well, any format is suitable for my purpose. Anyway a data frame like the one you proposed is what I'm looking for. The only problem with your code is that counts only the existent couples. I need to display the frequency of all the possible permutations.

Comment: I edited my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in base `R`:

```
# unique letter values
ut <- unique(Temp)

# expand to get a data.frame with all combinations
expnd <- data.frame(pair=do.call(paste0,expand.grid(ut,ut)),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# merge it with the table containing counts of all pair combinations
out   <- merge(expnd, table(pair=paste0(head(Temp,-1),tail(Temp,-1))), all=TRUE)

# turn NAs into zeroes
out$Freq[is.na(out$Freq)] <- 0

#   pair Freq
# 1   AA    1
# 2   AB    2
# 3   AC    1
# 4   BA    1
# 5   BB    0
# 6   BC    0
# 7   CA    1
# 8   CB    0
# 9   CC    1
```

with library `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(x=head(Temp,-1),y=tail(Temp,-1)) %>%
  count(x,y) %>%              # count combinations
  complete(x,y) %>%           # add missing combinations
  replace_na(list(n=0)) %>%   # make them zero
  unite(pair,x,y,sep='') %>%  # turn 2 columns into 1
  arrange(pair)               # sort

# # A tibble: 9 x 2
#   pair      n
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 AA        1
# 2 AB        2
# 3 AC        1
# 4 BA        1
# 5 BB        0
# 6 BC        0
# 7 CA        1
# 8 CB        0
# 9 CC        1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple base solution:

```
table(sapply(1:(length(Temp) - 1), function(x) paste(Temp[x:(x+1)], collapse = "")))

AA AB AC BA CA CC 
 1  2  1  1  1  1
```

If you really want to see all possible permutations you can use any package that will generate permutations with repetition. Below we use `gtools`.

```
library(gtools)
## Same as above
vec <- table(sapply(1:(length(Temp) - 1), function(x) paste(Temp[x:(x+1)], collapse = "")))

## Generate all permutations
myNames <- apply(permutations(3, 2, unique(Temp), repeats.allowed = TRUE), 1, paste, collapse = "")

## Initialize return vector
res <- integer(length(myNames))

## Add names
names(res) <- myNames

## Subset on names
res[names(res) %in% names(vec)] <- vec

res
AA AB AC BA BB BC CA CB CC 
 1  2  1  1  0  0  1  0  1
```

Comment: The second solution is what I'm looking for, but I'm getting this message:

`Error in permutations(3, 2, unique(Temp), repeats.allowed = TRUE) : 
  unused arguments (2, unique(Temp), repeats.allowed = TRUE)`

Comment: @aipam, I'm not sure what is going on... I just copied and pasted the code into a fresh R session and it works fine for me. The only thing I can think of is that you possibly have other libraries loaded that have a function called `permutations`.  For example there is a function from package `rje` called permutations that takes only takes one argument.  If you want, you can always makes sure you are using the proper library by using the scope operator `::` like so, `gtools::permutations`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)
b <- table(sapply(seq_along(Temp), function(x) paste0(Temp[x], Temp[x+1]))[-length(Temp)])

expand.grid(unique(Temp), unique(Temp)) %>% 
 unite(Var1, Var1, Var2, sep = "") %>% 
 left_join(as.data.frame(b,stringsAsFactors = F)) %>% 
 mutate(Freq=ifelse(is.na(Freq), 0, Freq))
  Var Freq
1  AA    1
2  BA    1
3  CA    1
4  AB    2
5  BB    0
6  CB    0
7  AC    1
8  BC    0
9  CC    1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(magrittr)
n <- length(Temp)
sapply(1:(n-1),function(i) paste(Temp[i:(i+1)], collapse = "")) %>% 
  factor(levels = paste0(rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 3), LETTERS[1:3])) %>%
  table()

AA AB AC BA BB BC CA CB CC 
 1  2  1  1  0  0  1  0  1
```